# Shell script: How to split line?

Tags: awk, sed, split, grep

here's my scanerio:

my input file like:

```
/tmp/abc.txt
/tmp/cde.txt
/tmp/xyz/123.txt
```

and i'd like to obtain the following output in 2 files:

first file

```
/tmp/
/tmp/
/tmp/xyz/
```

second file

```
abc.txt
cde.txt
123.txt
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through grep,

```
grep -o '.*/' file > file1.txt
grep -o '[^/]*$' file > file2.txt
```

- `.*/` Matches all the characters from the start upto the last `/` symbol.
- `[^/]*$` Matches any character but not of `/` zero or more times. `$` asserts that we are at the end of a line.

Answer (score 4):

Here is all in one single `awk`

```
awk -F\/ -vOFS=\/ '{print $NF > "file2";$NF="";print > "file1"}' input
```

```
cat file1
/tmp/
/tmp/
/tmp/xyz/
```

```
cat file2
abc.txt
cde.txt
123.txt
```

Here we set input and output separator to `/`
Then print last field `$NF` to `file2`
Set the last field to nothing, then print the rest to `file1`

Comment: Saying `delete the last field` is misleading as you only remove the text. The field is still there, if you removed the field then the last `/` would disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you already have an answer, but you might be interested in the following two commands:

```
basename
dirname
```

If they're available on your system, you'll be able to get what you want just piping through these:

```
cat input | xargs -l dirname > file1
cat input | xargs -l basename > file2
```

Enjoy!

Edit: Fixed per quantdev's comment.  Good catch!

Comment: Here is oneliner using the same: `while read a; do dirname "$a" >> f2.txt; basename "$a" >> f3.txt; done < f1.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` solution is probably the best, but here is a pure `sed` solution :

```
#n sed script to get base and file paths
h
s/.*\/\(.*.txt\)/\1/
w file1
g
s/\(.*\)\/.*.txt/\1/
w file2
```

Note how we hold the buffer with `h`, and how we use the write (`w`) command to produce the output files. There are many other ways to do it with sed, but I like this one for using multiple different commands.
To use it :

> > sed -f sed_script testfile

Answer (score 0):

Here is another oneliner that uses `tee`:
`cat f1.txt | tee >(xargs -n 1 dirname >> f2.txt) >(xargs -n 1 basename >> f3.txt) &>/dev/random`